# Reading pdfs with RMagick from https gives a not authorized error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, https, rmagick

I am trying to read a pdf and save the first page as an image. This method works for http, but it doesn't work for https.

```
require 'RMagick'

url = "http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/publications/reports/tud-ke-2008-07.pdf"
image = Magick::Image.read(url + "[0]")
=> [http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/publications/reports/tud-ke-2008-07.pdf[0]=>tud-ke-2008-07.pdf PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 27kb]

url = "https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202003%20-%20Machine%20Learning%20in%20Computer%20Chess.pdf"
image = Magick::Image.read(url + "[0]")
Magick::ImageMagickError: not authorized `//www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202003%20-%20Machine%20Learning%20in%20Computer%20Chess.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454
```

The policy.xml file looks like this without having edited it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<!--
  Configure ImageMagick policies.

  Domains include system, delegate, coder, filter, path, or resource.

  Rights include none, read, write, and execute.  Use | to combine them,
  for example: "read | write" to permit read from, or write to, a path.

  Use a glob expression as a pattern.

  Suppose we do not want users to process MPEG video images:

    <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="mpeg:decode" />

  Here we do not want users reading images from HTTP:

    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />

  Lets prevent users from executing any image filters:

    <policy domain="filter" rights="none" pattern="*" />

  The /repository file system is restricted to read only.  We use a glob
  expression to match all paths that start with /repository:

    <policy domain="path" rights="read" pattern="/repository/*" />

  Any large image is cached to disk rather than memory:

  Define arguments for the memory, map, area, and disk resources with
  SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB).  In addition, resource policies are maximums for
  each instance of ImageMagick (e.g. policy memory limit 1GB, -limit 2GB
  exceeds policy maximum so memory limit is 1GB).
-->
<policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="4GiB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1GB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="16EB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="SHOW" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="WIN" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PLT" />
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />
</policymap>
```

Comment: Do you have an imagemagick policy file that forbids https (popular following the imagetragick vulnerabilities) ?

Comment: I don't think I have a policy file. I only found one related thing online, but it was Heroku specific:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29657&p=133125&hilit=Magick%3A%3AImageMagickError%3A+not+authorize#p133125

and

https://gist.github.com/yanowitz/8329d8b27d8294ca7027f504326fd629

Comment: Default location is /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml - I think there is always such a file (although it may be empty). The error you get is the same as I get if I create such a policy

Comment: I don't have that directory in my apps, and I don't have a policy.xml anywhere on my computer. Could it be hosting platform-specific?

Comment: It's not part of your app. Exact location on disk would depend on how your hosting provider installed imagemagick.

Comment: I found the file on the server. Would it work to remove or edit the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your imagemagick policy file doesn't allow access to https. This is done with a directive that looks like

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
```

This was part of the recommended policy.xml following a recent round of imagemagick [security vulnerabilities](https://imagetragick.com).

You could of course edit policy.xml to remove this (I don't know off the top of my head whether imagemagick will complain if the file is missing entirely) however this may leave you open to these vulnerabilities if your hosting provider relied on these motivations

Another option is to download the file, and then ask Rmagick to read that local file - the policy only restricts ImageMagick from doing the https access itself.

Comment: It looks like the policy.xml already has that line, and several others, which I updated in my question. I might try removing that line, but could any of the others cause problems for reading pdfs from the web?

Comment: I removed that line, and tried again, but a new error: Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-w2acfoOL': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/583

Comment: Technically this answered my question, but I posted a new https-specific issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951979/reading-pdfs-with-rmagick-from-https-gives-a-unable-to-open-file-error